# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, set a password, and when computer restarted, I typed in a password that Ubuntu said is incorrect

Tags: password-recovery

> Installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, set a password
>   When computer restarted, I typed in a password that Ubuntu said is incorrect. >How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Restart Ubuntu
Hold Shift key during boot to start Grub menu
Highlight your image and press E to edit
Find the line starting with "Linux" and add rw init=/bin/bash to the end of that line
Press Ctrl + X to boot
Type in passwd username
Set your password

Info gathered from
 [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your Ubuntu PC and hold down the "Shift" key at boot to open the Grub Menu. Select the second option, "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-37-generic (recovery mode)". Then you will see a list of recovery options. Select the option "root- Drop to Root Shell Prompt". A root command prompt will appear and it will look like this: root@ubuntu:~#

Next type in the following command: mount -rw -o remount /

Now you can reset your password by typing these commands:

root@ubuntu:~# passwd username
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:

Reboot then you are all set.